# VB.NET syntax highlighting broken

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

The VB.NET syntax highlighting appears to be broken. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936054/no-console-output-from-memorystream-of-serialized-xml. When language is auto-detected the `'` used for the comments seems to start a string (that then does not end correctly) rather than a comment.

If language is specified using the hint `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` then only things in `<>` are highlighted (as stings) and *nothing* else

Comment: Typing `''` (two quotes) is a simple workaround for single-line comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing broken.

There are multiple tags on that question. One of them is [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) which has off-course the `lang-xml` language hint. As that tag is waaaaay more popular than VB.NET it comes first. And with that it picks that prettify hint.

To force VB.NET highlighting add the explicit language hint `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` before the appropriate code-block .

Remember that the hint needs to be on a single line with a blank line above and below it:

> lorum ipsum
>
> `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`
>
> ```
> Public Sub VBRocks()
>    Print "Rocking" ' this highlighting works
> End Sub
> ```

or use it with code fences:

> ````
> ```vb
> Public Sub VBRocks()
>    Print "Rocking" ' this highlighting works
> End Sub
> ```
> ````

Do note that the preview of the post can be off in corner cases.

---

Here is the result in action:

```vb
Public Sub VBRocks()
   Print "Rocking" ' this highlighting works
End Sub
```

---

code fences:

```vb
Public Sub VBRocks()
   Print "Rocking" ' this highlighting works
End Sub
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have tried adding the `lang-vb`, but that seems to remove nearly all the highlighting, except the lines `<DataContract()>` and <Datamember()> which use the same colouring as the strings. It seems then that what is broken is that the highlighter is preferring the tag language over the language hint. Which makes language hints pretty useless really.

Comment: I see that you've edited the question to add the 'lang-vb'  again, and it has worked. However, immediately before the edit showed, I was doing the exact same thing but with the results described in my above comment... :\

Comment: Hmm maybe I did indeed miss the extra new line below the hint. Muchos gracias!

Comment: reading this answer now in 2020, it seems that there is no longer any syntax highlighting for VB.NET?

Comment: @JohnRDOrazio works for me here on MSO.

Comment: @rene oh ok I see that there wasn't an actual example in action, just an explanation of how. Now that you added the example in action I can see it, thanks